# pass an array of headers to curl into a bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, curl

I am working on a script which is a test suite that would check all invalid headers case using curl.

I created a bunch of functions which allows me to construct headers tupe (field_name: field_value) with default testing value.

```
build_foo_header() {
  local FOO_KN=${1:-'X-App-Name'}
  local FOO_KV=${2:-'MyApp'}
  echo $FOO_KN: $FOO_KV
}
```

I would like to create some arrays in functions with either missing headers or headers with invalid values to test my app behavior.

So i created a sample function as it :

```
build_headers_invalid_X_App_Name_Value() {
  HEADERS=()

  # this array should contain all other required headers
  HEADERS[0]=$(build_foo_header X-App-Name BadValue)
  # HEADERS[1]= header that is required with default value
  # and son on for all the remaning required headers

  echo "${HEADERS[@]/#/-H}" 
}
```

However i can't get curl how to pass that array to curl ?

```
$(curl $(build_headers_invalid_X_App_Name_Value) myURl)
```

Seems to send a request to the first header in the HEADERS array.

I have approximatively 10 required headers that's why I would like to script it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is by echoing `"${HEADERS[@]/#/-H}"`, you lose any distinction between whitespace that occurred in an element of `HEADERS` and whitespace used to separate two elements in the output.

If you want to use a function, you need to just set a global array, then use that directly. No command substitution is needed or useful.

```
build_foo_header() {
  local FOO_KN=${1:-'X-App-Name'}
  local FOO_KV=${2:-'MyApp'}
  echo "$FOO_KN: $FOO_KV"
}

build_headers_invalid_X_App_Name_Value() {
  HEADERS=()

  # this array should contain all other required headers
  HEADERS[0]=$(build_foo_header X-App-Name BadValue)
  # HEADERS[1]= header that is required with default value
  # and son on for all the remaning required headers    
}

build_headers_invalid_X_App_Name_Value
curl "${HEADERS[@]/#/-H}" myUrl
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I will have lot of build_headers_XXX functions to handle each use case of missing or misspelled headers so I would like the array to be local to the function and then figure a way to pass it to the curl command (there will a bunch of curl call in my script). Sorry it's a bit more than the OP but if you won't mind give me hints :)

Comment: If you could pass the result as a string (via the output of your function), arrays wouldn't need to have been invented. `bash` simply doesn't have anything more complicated than a string that you can pass around as a first-class value.

Comment: You could run the function and `curl` in a subshell, as long as there isn't anything else you need to make global: `(build_headers; curl "${HEADERS[@]/#/-H}" myUrl)`. This way, `HEADERS` is global to the subshell in which the commands run, but disappears after that subshell exits.